# Generics C# - Passing a Dynamic Type as an Argument

Tags: c#, sql, linq, generics, types

I ran into a small issue when trying to use SQL Queries with LinQ.

The object I am receiving is as below:

```
public class Entity {
   public int EntityId { get; set; }
   public string TableName { get; set; } 
}
```

Basically I need to run a script similar to this ..

```
var entityQuery = _context.Database.SqlQuery<T>("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[" + TableName + "] WHERE [Id]=" + EntityId).ToList();
```

Now the problem is that I can only know what type of object "T" is from the "TableName" property. How would I be able to instantiate the class in order to pass it instead of T?

Thanks :)

---

For those getting confused this is the method I am working on:

```
public void ModifyData(Entity item)
{
  var table = item.TableName;
  var id = item.EntityId;

  var entityQuery = _context.Database.SqlQuery<T>("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[" + table + "] WHERE [Id]=" + id ).ToList();

  //more code below;
}
```

Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: T is generic type ...

Comment: I know .. I need to fill it in or else I wouldn't be able to pass the SQLQuery. The only thing is that I wouldn know the type as I receive it through the parameter "TableName" as shown above.

Comment: Did you want to get table name by generic type `T`?

Comment: How exactly are you receiving the type through 'TableName', which is an int? On a side note that is very confusing; having a property called 'TableName' that isn't actually a 'name' but a number, which also is apparently a 'type'.

Comment: you have to co Type type = Type.GetType("Namespace.MyClass, MyAssembly");..this will give you tyep from string

Comment: sorry that was a mistake on my part .. arranged :)

Comment: It looks like the query is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: This question has all the signs of an X Y problem, and the design flaws of the Titanic in an iceberg hitting competition ... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to pass a tableName ? and too in a "int tableName" ? Why dont use the entity type passed in  ? 
Well anyways, you can try something like this:

```
static string Data(string tableName, string columnNames, string orderBy)
{
  var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == tableName);
  using (var context = new BloggingEntities())
  {
    var data = Select(type, columnNames, orderBy, context);
    var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    return str;
  }
}

static string Select(Type type, string columnNames, string orderBy, BloggingEntities _dbContext)
{
  var data = _dbContext.Set(type).AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();
  var selectStatement = "new ( " + columnNames + ")";
  var filtered = data.Select(selectStatement).OrderBy(orderBy);
  return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(filtered);
}
```

Note: You may have to install this : `Install-Package System.Linq.Dynamic`

In your case you can directly use

```
var data = _dbContext.Set(type).AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();
```

Comment: can you select all columns instead of defining columnNames?

Comment: Yes. Thats what the line _dbContext.Set(type).AsNoTracking().AsQueryable(); does.
Something like

var data = _dbContext.Set(type).AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();
  return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);